# Problem viewing Excel date cell content in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, excel, datagrid

I'm loading an Excel sheet to `DataGrid` control in WPF. 
In cell in Excel sheet I have a value **1.6.2011** which is a date.

If I load this Excel file with this method:

```
private static DataSet LoadExcelFile(string file,string sheetName)
{
   string connString=   "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
                        "Data Source=" +  file + ";" + 
                        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
    var oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    try
    {
        // Open connection
        oledbConn.Open();

        // Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM ["+sheetName+"$]", oledbConn);

        // Create new OleDbDataAdapter
        var oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
        var ds = new DataSet();

        // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the worksheet.
        oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");

       return ds;
    }
    catch
    {
       throw  new Exception();
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close connection
        oledbConn.Close();
    }  

}
```

and then add the `DataSet` to the `DataGrid`:

```
Dps.ItemsSource = ExcelFile.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

then the problem is that value in the Excel sheet is 1-6-2001 but in WPF `DataGrid` it is viewed as `40695`.

What did I do wrong?  I think it it caused by the cell format in Excel. The data type of the cell in Excel is `DATE`.  I think this is the root of problem.  How to solve it?

Comment: Remove that try/catch block.  I can't imagine a good reason for catching an exception and throwing an new empty untyped `Exception`.  You lose all knowledge of what the cause of the original exception was, and your program still crashes.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 6-1-2011? If that's the case, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If in Excel it is actuall 6-1-**2011** (not 2001, typo?) then the 40695 represents an OLE date. You can therefore convert it via:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(40695);
```

which corresponds to 6/1/2011.

Use the above code in an IValueConverter to get the correct value to display in your DataGrid.